# How to make/set cookies in C# win form and web browser

Tags: cookies

Actually I don't know how to make **cookies** but i have something like this

```
 public CookieContainer GetCookieContainer()
        {
            CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

            foreach (string cookie in webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split(';'))
            {
                string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
                string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
                string path = "/";
                string domain = "yourweb";

                container.Add(new Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));// System.Net.CookieException at domain
            }

            return container;
        }
```

And something like this

```
DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

Cookie temp1 = new Cookie("cookies", "cookies", "FILE", "/");
            InternetSetCookie(
```

Do you have any suggest about this?

Answer (score 0):

It not possible to set cookie with domain that not matches to current loaded, you need to look at this point.
Also I would suggest - why not simply run Js snip?

Comment: Is there another way to do that?